# How update JavaScript cookies

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and wonder how to update the value of JavaScript cookie, I searched the internet but I couldn't understand it, any help?

Thanks

Comment: Just set it again with the new value...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Comment: Your google-fu is weak grasshoppa.

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work!! :/

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand?

Comment: I searched google to update the cookies, some says that just set it again, and some talked about expires date, I tried both ways, but neither worked, I'm getting confused.

Comment: If you have problems with code you wrote, you should include it in your question and properly explain the problem. What does "doesn't work" mean in this context? Did you have two cookies with the same name? Did the value not update?

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that I have two cookies with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.cookie = cookieName + '=' + encodeURIComponent(cookieValue) + '; domain=' + cookieDomain + '; path=/' + '; expires=' + expireDate.toUTCString();
```